# Why is the order of response different when calling async calls iteratively using for-each and for-of?

Tags: javascript, async-await, foreach, promise, for-of-loop

I am trying to wrap my head around working of javascript asynchronous functions in loop. Please follow the code snippet below

```js
const sleep = async(delay, input) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(input);
    }, delay);
  });
};

const promises = [sleep(500, 1), sleep(1000, 3), sleep(750, 2)];

(async() => {
  console.time('runTime');
  const res1 = [];
  const res2 = [];

  promises.forEach(async(promise) => {
    const res = await promise;
    res1.push(res);
  });

  console.log('logging forEach loop response-1', res1);

  for (const promise of promises) {
    const res = await promise;
    res2.push(res);
  }

  console.log('logging forEach loop response-2', res1);
  console.log('logging for loop response', res2);

  console.timeEnd('runTime');
})();
```

The output printed for above snippet is as below

```
logging forEach loop response-1 []
logging forEach loop response-2 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
logging for loop response [ 1, 3, 2 ]
runTime: 1.011s
```

Why is the order of output is different in `forEach response-2` than in `for response`? Any explanation will be very helpful.

EDIT: My apologies for the vauge question earlier. But there are two queries in particular which I am not able to unravel

1. How the whole snippet takes ~1s to execute. I understand the `logging forEach loop response-1` logs the empty array because callbacks in forEarch are async but entire forEach is not, and array is not yet populated after `forEach` has finished. But in the case of `for-of` loop shouldn't it have taken ~2.25s to execute, because it awaits for 0.5s, 1s and 0.75s respectively in each iteration?
2. How the sequence of output logged in `logging forEach loop response-2` is in the order of delay as opposed to `for-of` loop. Is it because in `forEach` an separate instance of anonymous callback is created and each callback is resolved in order of delay and hence the output. But if that's the case the my question #1 still unclear why `for-of` loop takes ~1s and not ~2.25s.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) I am able to understand the reason for #2 partially but still as per my understanding and what I read, why the runtime of `for-of` loop is not ~2.25s?

Comment: "*in the case of for-of loop shouldn't it have taken ~2.25s to execute, because it awaits for 0.5s, 1s and 0.75s respectively in each iteration?*" - that's because you started all the `setTimeout`s when you called `sleep` in `const promises = [sleep(500, 1), sleep(1000, 3), sleep(750, 2)];` - all at once, sleeping concurrently. A promise represents the result, not a task that is executed (again) when you `await` it. If you moved the `sleep` calls into the `for` loop (e.g. `for (const t of [500, 1000, 750]) await sleep(t)`) , the timeouts would be sequential.

Comment: "*How the sequence of output [of `res1` is in] order of delay? Is it because in forEach an separate instance of anonymous callback is created and each callback is [invoked] in order of delay?*" - yes.

Comment: many thanks @Bergi!!, this was very helpful especially the distinction of creating array with sleep as to calling it inside `for` loop.